# Multilingual support for struts2 tooltips

Tags: internationalization, struts2, tooltip

I need to show the text in the tooltips as per the user langguage.
I am using

> s:textfield name="userName"  title="This is the name of the user"/

How do i pick up the text "This is the name of the user" from a property file based on locale.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 textfiled already have parameter namely `tooltip`.All you need to use struts2 build in mechanism to fetch tool tip as per user locale.

here is what you have to do

```
<s:textfield name="myTextFiled" key="field.key" tooltip="%{getText('field.tooltip')}"/>
```

Please refer to the official documents for more details.
[textfield](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/textfield.html)

Comment: @SanmanGanthe: if it solved the problem accept the answer will help some one else with similar issue